# Does indexing a custom field in the below scenario will help with Non-Selective query error?

Tags: apex, soql, query, performance

**Background** :

- I have a object(`Foo__c`) with two columns(`Value__c`, `Type__c`).
  `Type__c` is a picklist, with two options(`A` and `B`) and `Value__c`
  is a text field.
- Running into Non-Selective query error when running query like
  this `SELECT Value__c FROM Foo__c WHERE Type__c = 'A' LIMIT 1` in
  after update trigger on Contact object.

So, I looked into the [Make SOQL query selective](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325257&type=1&mode=1) article and came up with the below
   calculation.

**Query 1**:(Total number of records in Object)

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Foo__c
```

1551449

**Query 2**:(Total number of records present in object where `Type__c = 'A'`)

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Foo__c WHERE Type__c = 'A'
```

807049

**Query 3**: (Total number of records present in object where `Type__c = 'B'`)

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Foo__c WHERE Type__c = 'B'
```

744400

Maximum number of records Query 2 or Query 3 can return before the query is considered non-selective is **127,552**, Is that right?

```
//Applying 10% of first one million and 5% of remaining records 
(0.1*1000000)+((1551449-1000000)*0.05) = 127,552
```

That means, if I make `Type__c` field indexed, it won't solve my non-selective query errors that I am running into in trigger context (for query 2 and 3), right?

I am going through [Make SOQL query selective](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325257&type=1&mode=1) but still want to make sure that what I am interpreting is correct.

**NOTE**: I ran Query 2 and 3 using Bulk API

Comment: Your numbers could use a bit more context.

Comment: @AdrianLarson added